# tinymce popup in bootstrap modal - focusin does not work in Chrome anymore?

Tags: google-chrome, tinymce-4, bootstrap-modal, focusin

I have this quick fix for overriding the built in block on focusin in bootstrap dialogs when using TinyMCE inside it.

It used to work on Chrome and Firefox. But now it does not work on Chrome anymore,

```
/**
* Prevent bootstrap dialog from blocking focusin
* http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:TinyMCE_in_a_boostrap_dialog
*/
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
    console.log(".mce-window length: " + $(e.target).closest(".mce-window").length);
    if ($(e.target).closest(".mce-window").length) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

Any ideas how can I fix it?